# jsonb aggegation in postgres select queries

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, jsonb

Given the following table:

```
# create table thing (id serial, tags jsonb);
# \d thing
                         Table "public.thing"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers                      
--------+---------+----------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('thing_id_seq'::regclass)
 tags   | jsonb   |
```

...and the following data:

```
insert into thing (tags) values ('{"tag1": ["val1", "val2"], "tag2": ["t2val1"]}');
insert into thing (tags) values ('{"tag1": ["val3", "val1"], "tag2": ["t2val1"]}');
insert into thing (tags) values ('{"tag1": ["val2", "val1"], "tag2": ["t2val2"]}');
```

How can I aggregate the results of a query that equates to "show me the number of matching rows and the set of `tag1` value that have a `tag2` value of `t2val1`?

The closes I can get is:

```
# select count(*), json_agg(tags) from thing where tags->'tag2'?'t2val1';
 count |                                             json_agg                                             
-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     2 | [{"tag1": ["val1", "val2"], "tag2": ["t2val1"]}, {"tag1": ["val3", "val1"], "tag2": ["t2val1"]}]
(1 row)
```

...but I really want:

```
 count |     tag1                                             
-------+-------------------------
     2 | ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
(1 row)
```

Comment: `select count(*), json_agg(tags->'tag1') from thing where tags->'tag2'?'t2val1';` is not the answer, but is not it more reasonable for your goals?..

Comment: btw - I'm not sure, but I think you can't merge json arrays in postgres  - you have to unnest, select distinct, aggregate or alike...